# How to apply word boundary in regex constructor?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

```
export enum KEYWORDS {
  CLASS = 1,
  METHOD,
  FUNCTION,
  CONSTRUCTOR,
  INT,
  BOOLEAN,
  CHAR,
  VOID,
  VAR,
  STATIC,
  FIELD,
  LET,
  DO,
  IF,
  ELSE,
  WHILE,
  RETURN,
  TRUE,
  FALSE,
  NULL,
  THIS
}


setTokenPatterns() {
    let keywordString: string = "";
    for (let keyword in KEYWORDS) {
      var isValueProperty = parseInt(keyword, 10) >= 0;
      if (isValueProperty) {
        keywordString += KEYWORDS[keyword].toLowerCase() + "|";
      }
    }

    this.keywordRegex = new RegExp(
      keywordString.slice(0, keywordString.length - 1)
    );

    this.tokenPatterns = new RegExp(
      this.keywordRegex.source +
        "|" +
        SYMBOL_REGEX.source +
        "|" +
        NUMBER_REGEX.source +
        "|" +
        STRING_REGEX.source +
        "|" +
        IDENTIFIER_REGEX.source,
      "g"
    );
  }
```

I've this program to get the regex for tokenizing my program. But the problem is the keywordRegex matches identifiers like "print" since "int" is from the regex keyword, so I want to apply word boundary for keywordRegex. How can I do that, I know the construct, it is \b, but I can't apply in RegExp constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here, but yes, you can use `\b` in regex for JavaScript. You simply have to escape the backslash `\\b`

Comment: I want the syntax to apply word boundary for my case.

Comment: You'd add `\b` at the start and end of your constructed regex and wrap the whole generated pattern in `(?:` and `)` so that your result is something like `\b(?:option1|option2|...)\b`

Comment: @ctwheels you should put that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` in your regex. You simply need to wrap your generated pattern in a non-capturing group `(?:)` and add `\b` at the start and end of the regex.

The result would look like `\b(?:option1|option2|...)\b`

Example:

```
"\\b(?:" +
this.keywordRegex.source +
"|" +
SYMBOL_REGEX.source +
"|" +
NUMBER_REGEX.source +
"|" +
STRING_REGEX.source +
"|" +
IDENTIFIER_REGEX.source +
")\\b"
```